# PHP call variable

Tags: php

i am using dreamweaver for my php. how do i get a variable called username from another page and display it to greet the user by name. i can login to the welcome page but getting and error when calling the variable i.e

```
<?php $_POST['username'] ?>
```

Error is Undefined index: username

Comment: Did you notice the typo in the variable name: username versus usename?

Comment: I edited your post to show the code you entered, but (unless I'm missing something) it should be `$_POST` and not `POST_`

Comment: Typing error. the code is Welcome <?php $_POST['usename'] ?>

Comment: This is the code from the login page. it should carry variable $loginUsername from the form field "username"

Comment: @Charles Then fix the code, you can edit your own posts. I've done this for you, but you can do this yourself as well.

Comment: Are you posting a username?  The $_POST super global only represents the last $_POST to the page.  If nothing is posted then $_POST is empty.  This question needs more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sessions for saving the user data:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Init the session:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Save variable:

```
$_SESSION["user"] = "name";
```

Get variable:

```
echo $_SESSION["user"];
```

Comment: You could also use http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php or any other site appearing when you google "php session tutorial"

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways to achieve this but probably the easiest is to create a session after the login and store the username in that session. Than, you can echo the username from that session on any page you want (within the session timespan of course).

set:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = "me";
```

Get:

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: let me try. i am a javscript oke but have to use php for what i am trying to achieve. thanks let me quickly edit my code

Comment: Seems okay, doesn't it? Of course, the string "me" needs to be replaced by the actual username that you just logged in. That probably from some form through a POST. I guess that will be $_POST['username'] or such. Be sure to do some input checking before you add the user data to the session.

Comment: I think you need to look at some basics again my friend. Sorry, can't help you out further more.

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
<?php $_POST['username'] ?>
```

and to print it out you should do:

```
<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not `<?php POST_['username'] ?>` but `<?php $_POST['username'] ?>`

Plus you can store the variables in cookies and sessions.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

I'm not sure dreamweaver allows cookies to be set, however.